# Module use of Python311.dll conflicts with this version of Python

Tags: python

[image]

Trying to use an add-on which everyone else has working fine but I keep getting this error, seems to be saying that the expat.py module which is packaged as part of the Blender installation is looking for a more recent version of Python than what is bundled with Blender - but this module is included with the Blender installation so I can't understand what's happening here... Any suggestions? I'm not experienced with Python I'm afraid.

Comment: Blender 3.2 is bundled with Python 3.10 so I suggest you use an older version of the addon or upgrade your Blender version. Latest is 4.0. You can also upgrade the built version of your current Blender installation but at this rate you might as well do one of the two others unless you absolutely have to stick with 3.2 and can't downgrade the addon

Comment: thanks for your suggestions. The add-on is working fine for other people with the standard blender installation and from what I can see it’s the expat.py which is included in the blender installation that is looking for python311.dll I’ve scoured my computer and removed any trace of any other python installation that may be affecting but there’s nothing showing anywhere… Any other ideas? I’ve tried last 10 versions of the add-on as well as multiple versions of blender from 3.2.0 to 4.0